# Find end point of an arc, given initial point of the arc, the angle to draw the sector, and radius of circle is known. Also find centre of circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, matlab, polar-coordinates

Hello Maths wizs,
                I am trying to implement a geometry problem in Octave/Matlab for a project but I am unable to figure out what mistake I am doing.
I have an arc of a circle(whose centre (A) is unknown) with a given radius 'R'. I know the starting point of the arc is point B(x1,y1), in rectangular form. I want to find the end point of the arc (point C) given the angle of the sector subtended at origin(theta) is provided as well.

[image]

I tried it using the following steps:

Step 1: Convert the points from rectangular form into polar form to get the radius and the angle of rotation.

Step 2: Add the radius obtained(as this conversion is done keeping 0,0 as origin) with the radius 'R' of the circle provided as input

Step 3: Use theta to find the next point on the Arc using the following formula:

x1 = (x * cos(sector_angle)) + (y *(sin(sector_angle)));

y1 = (-x * sin(sector_angle)) + (y * cos(sector_angle));

Step 4: Repeat step 3 to find the third point

Step 5: With 3 points on the circumference of the circle the centre can be calculated by solving three simultaneous equations of circle:
(x-h)^2 + (y-h)^2 = R^2

Now, after this I keep finding the centre at 0,0. I realized that adding the radius linearly did not solve any problem. I am trying to figure out a way to solve this issue, it will be a great help.

Additionally I also tried the school geometry way of using radius as two sides of isosceles triangles, finding the remaining angles and sides, using equation of straight lines to get the slope. I can't describe it fully here because it was more graphics method approach. But to summarize I got 2 equation with 4 variables hence unsolvable.

I read something about affine transforms to solve polar geometry problems but I couldn't figure that out.

If anyone can help me with my first algorithm, it will be highly appreciated.

Below is the code I wrote in Matlab:

A =[7 , 8];

%plot(A(1),A(2),'d')

axis([-20 20 -20 20])

hold on

Radius = 2;

alpha = atan(A(2)/A(1)); % angle betwen two points

sector_angle = pi/4;

radius = sqrt(A(1)^2 + A(2)^2)

common_radius = radius + Radius

x= common_radius * cos(alpha); % convert to polar form

y= common_radius * sin(alpha); % convert  to polar form

A1 = [x,y]

plot(A1(1),A1(2),'d')

hold on

%2nd point clockwise movement 
x1 = (x * cos(sector_angle)) + (y *(sin(sector_angle)));
y1 = (-x * sin(sector_angle)) + (y * cos(sector_angle));

B=[x1 y1]

plot(B(1),B(2),'d')

hold on

% 3rd point clock wise movement

x2 = (x1 * cos(sector_angle)) + (y1 *(sin(sector_angle)));

y2 = (-x1 * sin(sector_angle)) + (y1 * cos(sector_angle));

C=[x2 y2]

plot(C(1),C(2),'d')

hold on

% 4th point clock wise movement

x3 = (x2 * cos(sector_angle)) + (y2 *(sin(sector_angle)));

y3 = (-x2 * sin(sector_angle)) + (y2 * cos(sector_angle));

D=[x3 y3]

plot(D(1),D(2),'d')

hold on

% 5th point clock wise movement

x4 = (x3 * cos(sector_angle)) + (y3 *(sin(sector_angle)));

y4 = (-x3 * sin(sector_angle)) + (y3 * cos(sector_angle));

E=[x4 y4]

plot(E(1),E(2),'d')

hold on

% 6th point clock wise movement

x5 = (x4 * cos(sector_angle)) + (y4 *(sin(sector_angle)));

y5 = (-x4 * sin(sector_angle)) + (y4 * cos(sector_angle));

F=[x5 y5]

plot(F(1),F(2),'d')

hold on

% 7th point clock wise movement

x6 = (x5 * cos(sector_angle)) + (y5 *(sin(sector_angle)));

y6 = (-x5 * sin(sector_angle)) + (y5 * cos(sector_angle));

G=[x6 y6]

plot(G(1),G(2),'d')

hold on

% 8th point clock wise movement

x7 = (x6 * cos(sector_angle)) + (y6 *(sin(sector_angle)));

y7 = (-x6 * sin(sector_angle)) + (y6 * cos(sector_angle));

H=[x7 y7]

plot(H(1),H(2),'d')

hold on

% 9th point clock wise movement

x8 = (x7 * cos(sector_angle)) + (y7 *(sin(sector_angle)));

y8 = (-x7 * sin(sector_angle)) + (y7 * cos(sector_angle));

I=[x8 y8]

plot(I(1),I(2),'d')

hold on

%{
% Find centre of the circle 
Matrix_1 = [A(1)-B(1),A(2)- B(2);B(1)-C(1),B(2) - C(2)]

Matrix_1_inv = inv(Matrix_1)

Matrix_3 = [((A(1)^2)- (B(1)^2) + (A(2)^2)- (B(2)^2));((B(1)^2)-(C(1)^2) +
(B(2)^2) - (C(2)^2))]

Matrix_4 = 0.5 * (Matrix_3) .* Matrix_1_inv
%}

The plot of this is given below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpi4c.png)

Comment: The circle is not uniquely defined by the given information: to see this you can move point $A$ in a circle around point $C$. Have you also heard of the rotation matrix?

Comment: @TobyMak, thanks for your input. I have added the Matlab code in this edit. After 8 equally spaced points I get a perfect circle using the first point but the centre of circle is fixed at 0,0. This problem is unique to navigation. I know about rotation matrix and I believed it should give me a similar output as I got from the above code

Comment: @TobyMak I also tried complex rotational vector and I am getting similar output centred at 0,0. I believe information is not sufficient but the inputs provided seems to be the only ones available

Comment: I think this might be because of the Matlab rather than something else. I'm not familiar with Matlab, but what I can say is that Matlab topics are still on-topic on this site, so your question should be fine.